# matter.js create a rotating platform

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, matter.js

I need to create a platform that can be rotated with the mouse.  I tried to create a rectangle and connect it to the point with `Matter.Constraint.create()`, but such a platform can't be rotated with the mouse.  I haven't found an alternative in demos or examples

This is the code I use:

```
(function(){
    // Matter.js module aliases
    var Engine = Matter.Engine;
        World = Matter.World;
        Render = Matter.Render;
        Bodies = Matter.Bodies;
        Composites = Matter.Composites;
        Constraint = Matter.Constraint;
        MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint;

    // create a Matter.js engine
    var _engine = Engine.create(document.body);

    var rotatingPlatform = Bodies.rectangle(100, 200, 200, 30);

    World.add(_engine.world, [
    MouseConstraint.create(_engine),
    rotatingPlatform,
    Constraint.create({ pointA: {x: 100, y: 200}, bodyB: rotatingPlatform}),
    ]);

    // run the engine
    Engine.run(_engine);
})();
```

And the markup:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script src="matter-0.8.0.js"></script>
    <script src="myJsFile.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What can I do to make this platform rotate with the mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a little old but since no one has answered it.

Adding this to the bottom of your script works for me:

```
Matter.Events.on(_engine, "mousemove",  function(event) {
    if (Matter.Bounds.contains(rotatingPlatform.bounds, event.mouse.position) && event.mouse.button == 0) {
        targetAngle = Matter.Vector.angle(rotatingPlatform.position, event.mouse.position);
        Matter.Body.rotate(rotatingPlatform, targetAngle - rotatingPlatform.angle);
    }
});
_engine.world.gravity.y = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I love the idea, @oxdeadbeef, and strangely for me the mousemove event never fired.  I ended up doing this, which worked:

```
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  var mousePosition = {x: event.offsetX, y: event.offsetY};
  if (Matter.Bounds.contains(rotatingPlatform.bounds, mousePosition) && event.button == 0) {
    targetAngle = Matter.Vector.angle(rotatingPlatform.position, mousePosition);
    Matter.Body.rotate(rotatingPlatform, targetAngle - rotatingPlatform.angle);
  }
});
```

Thanks again for the idea.

Comment: I'm curious why the event didn't fire. I add it after Engine.run(). But no matter since your pure js event works too. Glad it helped!